# Has anyone ever implemented zmq or opencv for windows phone 8.1/Universal apps?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, windows-phone-8, zeromq

There are no nuget package supporting windows phone 8.1. Moreover a .net wrapper for ZMQ, clrzmq is available but it is also not working.

When I mark libzmq.dll as content, following exception :-

```
   An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in clrzmq.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'libzmq': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

When I compile it, there are numerous errors and sure seems like it is not able to read anything from it.

I just wanted to know if someone has ever successfully used Zmq in windows phone 8.1 app or a universal app?
I am first time dealing with .NET so I dont know much of the details.

Edit : In WindowsPhoneApp8.1 there at least was clrzmq nuget package but for the universal platform there is not a single nuget.

Comment: Please also try [github.com/ZeroMQ/clrzmq4](https://github.com/ZeroMQ/clrzmq4)... There you probably need to copy a new `libzmq.dll` and possibly `libsodium.dll` into the `amd64` folder, compiled for VS2012 or VS2015. Then you can go writing `ZFrames` :)

Comment: @metadings I have installed clrzmq nuget package and everything is fine at compile time. There are no compile time errors but at runtime, it is throwing the same Exception i.e. dllnotfoundexception. I am at a deadend here and really don't know where to proceed. I have implemented it in android but I have a very little knowledge about .net. Any insights would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You find my package in [nuget.org/packages/ZeroMQ](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ZeroMQ/).

Comment: Could not install package 'ZeroMQ 4.1.0.21'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.                 This is the error when I try to download your package. I was earlier doing with clrzmq nuget package.

Comment: Ya, well... This is currently built just for .NET 4.0 (client profile)... You should do `git clone https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4` and recompile the project.

Comment: You are writing a Phone project: do you have managed and native projects in your one project? I do need to know, to set whether C libraries should just be called `__Internal` or by the name `libzmq`.

Comment: Yes I have a single project only for both.

Comment: I was able to download clrzmq nuget package in my project. Everything would compile just fine but as soon as I try to run it, dllnotfoundException in clrzmq.dll is thrown. it's not able to find libzmq in clrzmq.dll.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with your package clrzmq...

Comment: Sorry to bother you once again, I just want to know whether it's possible to integrate zmq using     https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4 in a windows phone 8.1 universal app. If it's not I will start with some alternative as I have not yet seen a single example on the internet where anyone has successfull integrated it.

Comment: Yes you can do so, but it will be difficult for you... 1. You need to download (`git clone https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4`) and recompile this for `WindowsPhoneApp`. 2. You also likely need to download `libzmq`, `libsodium`, `libpgm`, and recompile this to be used with `Microsoft Visual C++ 2012` or later (the one already installed, I'm actually using `MSVC2010`).

Comment: Thanks @metadings for your help. I will try to get it working.